# 'int' object is not callable when called method of instance class

Tags: python

I don't know how to fix it but I think my code is clear. I am a beginner level python learner.

Here, I made a class `Hero` that has the method `attack`. However, when I called the method it says, there is an error 'int' object is not callable.

```py
class Hero(object):
    def __init__(self, name, hp, att_pwr, def_pwr ):
      self.name = name
      self.health = hp
      self.attack = att_pwr
      self.defense = def_pwr

    def attack(self):
      print(self.name + ' is attacking')


Hero1 = Hero('Arif', 75, 50, 40)
Hero1.attack()
```

Comment: You are using the same name `attack` as a an attribute as well as a class method.

Answer (score 2):

Look closely, you have an attribute and a method named `attack`. The class is trying to call the attribute instead of the method. Here is the class that works!

```py
class Hero:
    def __init__(self, name, hp, att_pwr, def_pwr):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = hp
        self.att_pwr = att_pwr
        self.def_pwr = def_pwr

    def attack(self):
        return self.name + " is attacking"


Hero1 = Hero("Arif", 75, 50, 40)
Hero1.attack()
```

This prints out:

```
>> 'Arif is attacking'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help iam still a beginner so i didnt know its works like that. Can you share python exercises espicialy for data science to me? Maybe a link or web. It will very helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have an attribute called `attack` as well as a method with the same name. Maybe you should rename the `attack` attribute to something else, for example `attack_points`.

```
class Hero(object):
    def __init__(self, name, hp, att_pwr, def_pwr ):
        self.name = name
        self.health = hp
        self.attack_points = att_pwr
        self.defense = def_pwr

    def attack(self):
        print(self.name + ' is attacking')


Hero1 = Hero('Arif', 75, 50, 40)
Hero1.attack()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an object class and attack is a property so, you'll use -

```py
Hero1.attack
```